# Is there some analytical result for Wright-Fisher SDE?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Are there ***already known*** analytical results (e.g. Laplace transform) about the Wright-Fisher SDE
$$dY=(A-(A+B)Y)dt+C\sqrt{Y(1-Y)}dW$$
with $A$, $B$ and $C$ parameters?

---

---

If so, could you please quote some reference?